# VBA | Excel <--> Word | Can't add border to first row

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I would like to create a table with some headings and add rows to that table.

**Creating the table:**

```
 Dim objRange As Word.Range
 Dim objTable As Word.Table
 Dim celTable As Word.Cell
 
 Set objRange = oDoc.Bookmarks("tbl").Range
 oDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 1, 6
 Set objTable = oDoc.Bookmarks("tbl").Range.Tables(1)
             
 objTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
 
 With objTable
    .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "A"
    .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "B"
    .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "C"
    .Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "D"
    .Cell(1, 5).Range.Text = "E"
    .Cell(1, 6).Range.Text = "F"
    
    .Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Cell(1, 3).Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Cell(1, 4).Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Cell(1, 5).Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Cell(1, 6).Range.Font.Bold = True
    
    'for testing reasons only one cell.
    .Cell(1, 1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).Visible = True
    .Cell(1, 1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
 End With

'Adding rows to the table
 For Each x In collection
    Dim newRow As Word.Row
    Set newRow = objTable.Rows.Add()
    Set objRange = newRow.Range
    newRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "..."
    newRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = "..."
    newRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = "..."
    newRow.Cells(4).Range.Text = "..."
    newRow.Cells(5).Range.Text = "..."
    newRow.Cells(6).Range.Text = "..."
  Next x
```

My problem is, after adding the rows, the border won't be added to the first row (even though I added the border to the first cell in the first row). The border appears instead at the end of the table (last row).

Answer (score 0):

Because your table only has a single row when you add it the border is interpreted as belonging to the table rather than the cell. If you add one or more rows before you add the border you will get the border you want.

```
 With objTable
   With .Rows(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom)
      .Visible = True
      .LineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
   End With
 End With
```